# Get line width and inner sep of a TikZ node

Tags: tikz

Is it possible to retrieve a node's `inner sep` and `line width` using the key tree? My exact use case is below.

I want to find the coordinates of the red marks in the image below, but not using the method I've used below. Basically I want what would be the `north east` anchor (or some other anchor on a rectangle) if it were to sit in the middle of the border line instead of the outer edge, as well as if it were to lie on the node's contents before `inner sep` is added. I don't want to use duplicate "phantom" nodes as I have below because in my use case the node's contents might be messy.

I also realize I can just save the `line width` and `inner sep` globally by using `\pgfmathsetlength{}{}`, applying them to the node and using the same macros to navigate relative to `north east`, or in similar fashion by defining custom keys. But I'd really like to ask the node directly, as though these values were specified as literals in the node's options like `\node [inner sep=1.2em] {};`.

Image:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \node [draw, line width=5pt, inner sep=8pt] (A) {foo};

  \node [draw=cyan, line width=2pt, inner sep=8pt] (B) {\phantom{foo}};
  \node [line width=0pt, inner sep=0pt] (C) {\phantom{foo}};
  \node [line width=0pt, inner sep=8pt] (D) {\phantom{foo}};

  % Basically I don't want to use nodes C and D, I want everything relative to A
  \draw [red] plot [mark=x] coordinates { (C.north east) };
  \draw [red] plot [mark=x] coordinates { (D.north east) };
  \draw [green] plot [mark=x] coordinates { (A.north east) };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess this question is relevant to the approach I'm trying to take: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15204/is-there-a-way-to-set-a-global-key-value-using-pgfkeys

Comment: You may get more response to this question on https://tex.stackexchange.com/.